# Excel - VBA to convert formulas to values on a sheet with an applied autofilter

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any way to efficiently convert all formulas on a sheet to values when there is an autofilter applied to the sheet?

I've explored saving the autofilter parameters, unfiltering to paste values, then refiltering using the saved parameters.. found some code that works but that is far too risky (and evidently only works with basic filtering logic used)

Would love to avoid a "for each cell" if possible, as some reports on sheets can be rather lengthy

Comment: Do you mean the formulas of both, the visible and 'unvisible' range?

Comment: Yes, the 'unvisible' filtered out range as well - it looks like I could maybe "do" okay the code I made to select special cells - formulas only, and do a for each cell in that range .value = .value, but wasn't sure if there was a wholesale method

Answer (score 0):

### Convert Formulas in Filter Worksheet To Values

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub FilteredToValues()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") ' adjust!
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.UsedRange
    
    If Not sws.FilterMode Then ' the worksheet is not in filter mode
        srg.Value = srg.Value ' or whatever
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' When the worksheet is in filter mode, that means that at least
    ' one row is hidden. It also means that at least one row, the header row,
    ' is visible. Thus no error handling is necessary.
    
    Dim arg As Range
    
    ' Convert the visible range.
    
    ' Reference the visible rows.
    Dim vrg As Range: Set vrg = srg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    
    ' Convert by looping through the areas of the visible range.
    For Each arg In vrg.Areas
        arg.Value = arg.Value
    Next arg
    
    ' Convert the hidden range.
    
    ' Reference the visible cells in the first column.
    Dim vcrg As Range: Set vcrg = Intersect(srg.Columns(1), vrg)
    
    Dim urg As Range, cel As Range
    
    ' Combine the hidden cells of the first column into a range.
    For Each cel In srg.Columns(1).Cells
        If Intersect(cel, vcrg) Is Nothing Then
            If urg Is Nothing Then Set urg = cel Else Set urg = Union(urg, cel)
        End If
    Next cel
    
    ' Reference the hidden rows.
    Dim hrg As Range: Set hrg = Intersect(urg.EntireRow, srg)
    
    ' Convert by looping through the areas of the hidden range.
    For Each arg In hrg.Areas
        arg.Value = arg.Value
    Next arg
    
    MsgBox "Formulas converted to values.", vbInformation
 
End Sub
```

Comment: No. But please elaborate. You can easily test the code: just put some values in e.g. `A1:A10`, then in the adjacent columns put a formula e.g. `=A1`, select and filter the range manually (uncheck some values) and run the code.